# Meaning of a C code snippet

Tags: c

I'm reading the code of a project and I found a part that I couldn't understand:

```
void (*pEpInt_OUT[7])(void) =
{
  EP1_OUT_Callback,
  EP2_OUT_Callback,
  EP3_OUT_Callback,
  EP4_OUT_Callback,
  EP5_OUT_Callback,
  EP6_OUT_Callback,
  EP7_OUT_Callback,
};
```

Is it a function? If yes, what is its name? Or is it something else?

Comment: It's an array of function pointers. The name of the array is `pEpInt_OUT`, it consists of 7 entries, and each entry contains a pointer to a function which takes no arguments and returns no value.

Comment: It's like you found the real-world code for the old quip: "C isn't that hard: void (*(*f[])())() defines f as an array of unspecified size, of pointers to functions that return pointers to functions that return void."

Comment: Another interesting question is, why was this post down-voted 3 times? It is properly formatted, OP specifically mentions that he or she cannot understand a given piece of code, and an additional effort is shown at the bottom of the post. How else would OP get an answer to this question? Googling it up just doesn't sound like something that is going to work.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting downvoted.  Like @Two-BitAlchemist said, this is an example of some of C's more complicated syntax, and I'm not sure how you would even structure a search query to get information on it if you didn't already know about function pointers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an array of 7 function pointers. Each of the entries points to a function which takes void and returns void; `void EP1_OUT_Callback( void )`.

Comment: ...and those functions are EP1_OUT_Callback, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It is a declaration and initialization of array of pointers to functions, while there have to be declarations of the functions `void EPx_OUT_Callback(void);` (x is from 1 to 7) somewhere in the code.